# Compare DOM node Value to string Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I'm running simple JavaScript for my homework.JS is accessing XML table with DOM. When I run this code:

```
...
var famstatus = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('famstatus');
for ( var i = 0 ; i<employee.length; i ++ )
{
document.getElementById("nam").innerHTML += famstatus[i].childNodes[0].textContent + " ";
}
...
```

I get:

```
Single Single Married Single Married.... etc.
```

However when I try to include an IF statement it doesn't achieve the expected results. Here is what I want to do:

```
...
for ( var i = 0; i < employee.length ; i++ )
{
   if ( famstatus[i].childNodes[0].textContent === "Single" ) 
   {
   alert("found"); 
   }
   else alert("not");
}
...
```

The script never alerts "found", I get only "not".

Comment: You look like you have 3 "=" signs when comparing in your condition?

Comment: Yeah I tried both == and === and neither worked.

Comment: add the console.log("famstatus[i].childNodes[0].textContent") and look at console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see what document you are working with so it is hard to debug, but there may be other text that isn't apparent so the strings aren't equal. Try replacing

```
if ( famstatus[i].childNodes[0].textContent === "Single" )
```

with

```
if ( famstatus[i].childNodes[0].textContent.indexOf("Single") > -1 )
```